# Proxy - Application Insights

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I am using application insights on an on-prem server in our corporation. I have set up the key and everything works when I run it on my machine. However, once I put it on the production server, it does not work.

I have run PerfView to see what the issue might be. Of course, it is not making a successful http call to Azure. So I need to figure out how to set up a proxy for the Application Insights part of my application. Every tutorial that I have found only talk about how to do it for .Net Framework and not .Net Core.

Does anyone have some sample code on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone sees this, AppInsights does support proxies. The [AppInsights configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/#configuration) options include both `httpProxyUrl` and `httpsProxyUrl`. Furthermore, the default value for those parameters are pulled from `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable respectively.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration#redirect-traffic-to-the-different-endpoint - You can override endpoint to any custom endpoint you have. Ofcourse, the code running in you endpoint should forward data to the original backend.
I dont think Application Insights allows user to specify proxy settings. You can have a proxy configured for your entire server, but not specific to application insights.